# How to condense a for loop with a print function?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm printing the columns of a dataset with specific formatting. I'm not satisfied with code I currently have and was hoping someone could suggest a way of condensing this to a single line.

Here's the code I'm trying to simplify:

```
# What columns are in this dataset
print('\nColumns are:')
for x in ['a','b','c']: # some list, could be df.columns
    print(f'\t{x}')
```

**Reason for condensing:**

1. I'm developing in a notebook, thus have my output below my code.
2. When the code is long (as in the case of many columns/lists), the code looks important. It's not so it's distracting.
3. With condensed code, ***readability on the output*** is increased.

Comment: Why do you need to condense the code any further? I know people like to use the shortest code possible, but for something like this use your time to solve more meaningful problems.

Comment: Almost all editors have a code-collapsing feature that allows you to hide blocks of code like functions, loops, classes, etc. That may be of use to you as well!

Comment: Edited the Q to answer that @Tony

Comment: @YaakovBressler - the additional reasons for condensing your code are still not valid reasons for this optimisation. Do you not have windows which scroll in your notebook? Or, as SyntaxVoid said, an IDE with code collapsing? And I completely disagree with your third point "With condensed code, readability on the output is increased." - readability of _code_ is more important! But even more so, a developer's time is _expensive_, why are you bothering with this!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(f"\t" + ("\t").join(["a","b","c"]))
```

Comment: What do you need the `f` for on the first tab?

Comment: It could be in the first or second tab it just needs to be somewhere so that the string is formatted

Comment: Why not simply `print("\t" + "\t".join(["a","b","c"]))`  ?

Comment: Without it the \t won't read as a tab it'll just print the string "\t"

Answer (score 1):

Readable code > short code but if you insist

Creates a generator, unpacks it, and prints elements

```py
data = ["1", "2", "3"]
print(*[f'\t{x}' for x in data])
```

Comment: No need to specify `sep` here.

Comment: I thought `sep` was a space by default? But you're right it has the same output either way. Interesting.

Comment: A few extra spaces won't affect tabular width. It's the same output even with `sep = '    '` (4 spaces)